# Huge performance penalty in gbit link with ip forwarding / masquerade through clear VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, performance, openvpn

I have a problem with IP forwarding between my home computer and a remote server (from online.net). My home connection is a 1 Gbit/s FTTH and the remote server has a 2.5 Gbit/s bandwidth.

## The context

I'm running a **clear** OpenVPN tunnel between my home computer and a remote server at online.net. For the moment, I don't use any encryption so I don't face any performance penalty due to encryption.

Server machine : Intel Atom C2750 / 2GB of RAM / SSD
Client machine : VMware hosted Ubuntu server 16.04 64 bit with 8 GB of RAM / SSD / Intel i5 (Mac mini 2013 behind)

**server** openvpn command:

```
 # openvpn --dev tun --proto tcp-server --port 11000 --ifconfig 10.200.0.1 10.200.0.2 --cipher none --auth none --fragment 0 --mssfix 0 --tun-mtu 48000 --sndbuf 0 --rcvbuf 0
```

**client** openvpn command:

```
 # openvpn --dev tun --proto tcp-client --port 11000 --ifconfig 10.200.0.2 10.200.0.1 --cipher none --auth none --remote dedibox --fragment 0 --mssfix 0 --tun-mtu 48000 --sndbuf 0 --rcvbuf 0
```

I've set up a vsftpd server on the remote server. If I download something from the remote FTP server through the OpenVPN tunnel, I'm at full speed.

```
lftp aixki@10.200.0.1:~> pget 1GB.dat
1073741824 bytes transferred in 11 seconds (95.68 MiB/s)
```

## The problem

The problem is when I want to access the internet from the client through the OpenVPN tunnel.

Let's add a route on the client machine for a particular website from which I test my download speed using wget/curl.

```
ip route add 62.34.91.0/24 via 10.200.0.1
```

Next, allow ipv4 forwarding on the remote server :

```
> # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And finally, allow VPN connections back and forth to the web :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And when I test my download speed from the client :

```
wget -O /dev/null http://3-ipv4.testdebit.info/fichiers/1000Mo.dat
...
2016-05-17 20:24:45 (17.7 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [1000000000/1000000000]
```

So that's almost 5 times less than when I download a file from the remote server using the VPN tunnel.

## What could be the reason ?

1. The link from the remote server to the 3-ipv4.testdebit.info website is slow ? No it's not, using the same wget from the remote server directly and I get 225 MB/s
2. The remote server can't handle receiving and sending the same amount of data at the same time at 1 Gbit/s ? Yes it can. I've done an FTP file transfer from the server and downloaded at the same on the remote server using wget, I was at 100+ MB/s on both transfer.
3. CPU overhead ? According to top, I'm using 15% of CPU capacity, so I don't think it's due to CPU.
4. iptables masquerading all packets ? I think it is, but I'm not sure. Can someone confirm/deny ?

Any help is highly appreciated, it gives me headaches since two days ! If you need any logs or TCP dump, I can give it to you.

---

## Edit 2016/05/22 at 14:09 GMT

I've dumped TCP packets using tcpdump **on the server**. All the dumps are available here :
http://163.172.210.224/dumps/

Here are the details about each file :

- `dump-server-direct-eth0.pcap` Dump eth0 of a direct http download from the server. No VPN neither ip forwarding used here. Command used (I filter out my IP address used for ssh connection): `tcpdump -i eth0 '((not net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) and port 80)' -C 100 -vvv -w dump-server-direct-eth0.pcap`
- `dump-server-forward-http-[tcp|udp]-eth0.pcap` Dump eth0 when the client download an http file through the UDP/TCP OpenVPN tunnel, using IP forwarding. Command used (I filter out my IP address used for ssh connection):
  `tcpdump -i eth0 '((not net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) and (port 80 or port 11000))'  -C 100 -vvv -w dump-server-forward-http-[tcp|udp]-eth0.pcap`
- `dump-server-forward-http-[tcp|udp]-tun0.pcap` Same as above, but this time capturing from tun0 interface. Command used:
  `tcpdump -i tun0 -C 100 -vvv -w dump-server-forward-http-[tcp|udp]-tun0.pcap`
- `dump-server-http-through-tcp-tunnel-eth0.pcap` Dump eth0 when the client download an ftp file through the UDP/TCP OpenVPN tunnel, *without* IP forwarding.  The http server is hosted on the OpenVPN server itself and I use the OpenVPN server address to connect to the server (10.200.0.1), so there's no IP forwarding at all. Command used (I filter with the client IP address):
  `tcpdump -i eth0 'net YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY'  -C 100 -vvv -w dump-server-ftp-through-tcp-tunnel eth0.pcap`
- `dump-server-http-through-tcp-tunnel-tun0.pcap` Same as above, but this time capturing from tun0 interface. Command used:
  `tcpdump -i tun0 -C 100 -vvv -w  dump-server-http-through-tcp-tunnel-tun0.pcap`

---

## Edit 2016/05/19 at 10:31 GMT

The comments and answers I get talk about the fact that I use TCP protocol with OpenVPN instead of udp. As I say in my post above, there's no speed performance issue between my server and my home computer through the TCP VPN tunnel :

```
lftp aixki@10.200.0.1:~> pget 1GB.dat
1073741824 bytes transferred in 11 seconds (95.68 MiB/s)
```

But to please everyone and stop the remarks about tcp versus udp, here's a test using udp :

**server**:

```
# openvpn --dev tun --proto udp --port 11000 --ifconfig 10.200.0.1 10.200.0.2 --cipher none --auth none --fragment 0 --mssfix 0 --tun-mtu 48000 --sndbuf 393216 --rcvbuf 393216
```

**client**:

```
# openvpn --dev tun --proto udp --port 11000 --ifconfig 10.200.0.2 10.200.0.1 --cipher none --auth none --fragment 0 --mssfix 0 --tun-mtu 48000 --sndbuf 393216 --rcvbuf 393216 --remote dedibox
```

iperf3 test from the server to the client using the udp vpn tunnel :

```
#  iperf3 -c 10.200.0.2  -i 1 -p 5201 -f m -b 1G -u

Connecting to host 10.200.0.2, port 5201
[  4] local 10.200.0.1 port 55287 connected to 10.200.0.2 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   111 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec  14265
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15258
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15258
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15260
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15259
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15258
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15253
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15266
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15255
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   119 MBytes  1000 Mbits/sec  15262
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.16 GBytes   993 Mbits/sec  0.763 ms  141473/150989 (94%)
[  4] Sent 150989 datagrams

iperf Done.
```

And finally, a speed test from the client and a speed test server hosted at testdebit.info, through my vpn tunnel :

```
# ip route add 62.34.91.3 via 10.200.0.1

# wget -O /dev/null http://3-ipv4.testdebit.info/fichiers/1000Mo.dat
/dev/null               100%[============================>] 953.67M  12.4MB/s    in 79s
2016-05-19 12:27:40 (12.1 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [1000000000/1000000000]
```

Conclusion : no difference between UDP and TCP !

As I said, the problem is with iptables or ipv4.ip_forwarding, but **not with OpenVPN / TCP / UDP**

Comment: Why are you using TCP as OpenVPN transport protocol? See also: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/461

Comment: Because UDP protocol gave me bad performance. Details can be found [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=21738)

Also, as I say in my post, speed is very good between my host and my server through the tunnel, it's only when iptables is used that things get complicated. So, it's not related to the protocol.

Comment: Can you test your bandwidth between servers using iperf? I'd like to see UDP performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924212/iperf-testing-tcp-vs-udp

Comment: Well, it's already done in the post I gave you in my previous comment, right [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=21738). As you can see, I get 50% performance penalty when using UDP instead of TCP. Maybe the VPS server or my ISP throttle massive UDP datagrams. I've event got my VPS server suspended because they detected a flood while doing these iperf tests. They thought there was an attack going on.

Comment: In Your OpenVPN's forum thread I see only iperf TCP performance test through UDP tunnel, what I've meant was a iperf UDP performance test directly between servers using UDP transport. What I also saw, you didn't increase OpenVPN server (or disabled sever setting) buffers when setting up UDP tunnel. What latency (again via UDP or ICMP) do you have through UDP tunnel and without it.

Comment: Ok I see. So I ran another test of iperf3 with dp protocol through my udp openvpn tunnel, and this time I get  ~1000 Mbits/s ! But this doesn't solve the problem of the performance penalty when I use iptables/ipv4.ip_forward ;-)

Regarding the latency, do you know how to measure it exactly ?

Comment: I'd look into CPU utilization and MTU, namely reducing MTU when running over VPN. And you can also collect a tcpdump for your external interface for both cases and compare/analyze it.

Comment: @aixki just ping it from Linux OS and in the end you will see something like: `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.551/17.904/18.874/0.982 ms`

Comment: High latency in VPN channel and low buffer sizes in TCP sockets can explain low throughput.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski : Latency is pretty good I think.rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.200/13.333/13.487/0.126 ms

Comment: @AlecIstomin CPU utilization is OK as I say in my question post. MTU is set to 48000 for the tunnel.

Comment: @aixki typical MTU is 1500, you must be looking on something else. Try to set it on the lower side of say 1400

Comment: @AlecIstomin I've added a lot of dumps to my post. From what I can see, there's a huge difference in the packet length when I do IP forwarding. For example, when I download a file on the FTP server hosted on the OpenVPN server directly, I get 48000 bytes packet length. But when I do IP forwarding and download something on a remote FTP site through the tunnel, I get 1500 bytes packet length. I don't know how to fix that, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a very quick look at your last capture file.  We can immediately see that the RTT on the end-to-end TCP session is around 50ms or worse.  Your client is advaertising a window around 3MB (not 300MB as I originally typed).  Put those together and you have an absolute maximum 480Mbps assuming infinitely fast hardware at each end of the TCP connection.  Presumably neither end is infinitely fast.
So if I were you I would either:

accept the performance you get (depending upon actual requirements)

or:

graph the RTT across the whole session to gain accuracy
use bandwidth delay product to understand exactly what bandwidth is max for a single TCP flow.
 
investigate where the components of delay come from (e.g. by installing a tap at the tunnel server)

UPDATE:
The delay is caused on the tunnel server.  The capture files don't make this obvious but the end-to-end latency is much higher than I originally thought.  The host-based capture files obscure the length of time each packet spends in the server.  Ideally you should make a capture on the client and I think that will show much higher RTTs.

dump-server-forward-http-tcp-eth0 frame 17854 is a case in point.  It contains data from the Internet host that is (supposedly) transmitted to the client in 17856.  However 17856 is not acknowledged until 18614, some 222ms later.  Allowing for a 40ms RTT to the client including some processing, then the server is adding at least 180ms to the one-way trip from reception from the Internet host to puttting it on the wire toward the client.  Given that frame 17854 is clearly not a physical frame but has been reassembled (possibly erroneously) there may also be similar delays towards to Internet host.

If the RTT is 222 ms and the RWIN is 3MB then TCP can only deliver 13.5Mbps

It looks to me as though there is TCP segmentation offload enabled and that for whatever reason the TCP is being processed on the tunnel server when you really only want it forwarded.  You now need to investigate why this might be the case.

UPDATE:  I also just noticed that you say CPU is only 15%.  If this refers to the tunnel server, you say that it's a C2750 Atom, 8-core.  With a multi-thread CPU any sustained CPU load at or a bit above 100% / number-of-cores (in your case 12.5%) can be a single main thread saturating one core.

Comment: Just had a look at your other file showing the encapsulation.  Although it may be good practise not to use TCP for encapsulation, the encapsulating TCP protocol is not a limiting factor in your case.  That doesn't in itself rule out the possibility that TCP processing overhead on the tunnel server is causing unnecessary latency in the end-to-end flow.  Don't forget the rule of thumb that says for conventional TCP processing it takes 1Hz per bps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I forgot to mention that I'm not a network expert at all, so I'm a little bit lost when you talk about RTT Graph etc... But here's the news : I've made an SSH tunnel between my server and my PC, and using the socket created by the ssh tunnel with curl I can get something like 90 MB/s, which is almost full speed. And as far as I know, ssh is over TCP so that's the same thing as OpenVPN **minus** ip forwarding and masquerade. If you want, I can also dump the TCP packets generated by the ssh tunnel.

Comment: Sorry for the tech-speak then.

Comment: Don't be, that's what this place is for :)  Anyway I've found that I am achieving 30MB/s with softether vpn that primarily focus on speed. Furthermore, I've found this article which could be an answer to my problem http://www.networkworld.com/article/2224654/cisco-subnet/mtu-size-issues.html

Comment: Max TCP data throughput is governed by a formula RWIN (receive buffers) divided by RTT (Round-Trip Time).  You've got a nice big buffer (300kB) but latency may be affecting you.  You have two Internet trips to worry about plus processing time on the tunnel server.  This adds up to over 50ms for the few examples that I looked at.  Hence the absolute max speed of 480Mbps.  I'll try to think about your next steps

Comment: It's not an MTU issue as far as I can see.  Are you the only user of the server (and its 2.5Gbps link)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand from your answer and the article I posted above. But, how could we explain that I get ~90MB/s through SSH tunnel ? There's still those two internet trips going on. That really occupies my mind. And yes I'm the only user of the vps server.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  Are you saying that you ssh from your client via the server to another Internet server and get 90MB/s?

Comment: That's right. I open an ssh tunnel from my client with ssh -D, and then downloading with curl through the socks5 proxy gives me 90MB/s. Weird right?